# HumanizerMetadataProvider implementation not working for Razor Page model

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking to setup an ASP.NET Core application so that property names in a model are automatically 'humanised' in some way (e.g. spaces added to property names).

For example, here is my SystemSettings model:

```
public class SystemSettings : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Description = "Emails sent from system will be sent from this address.")]
    public string EmailFromAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Description = "Name of the organisation")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Description = "Name of the web application")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

My aim is that the Display Name for each property is set automatically by default (but can be overridden). For example, the 'EmailFromAddress' property would by default have the label 'Email From Address').

To achieve that aim, I saw a snippet of code like this:

```
public class HumaniserMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        var propertyAttributes = context.Attributes;
        var modelMetadata = context.DisplayMetadata;
        var propertyName = context.Key.Name;

        if (IsTransformRequired(propertyName, modelMetadata, propertyAttributes))
        {
            modelMetadata.DisplayName = () => SplitCamelCase(propertyName);
        }
    }

    private static string SplitCamelCase(string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(
            Regex.Replace(
                str,
                @"(\P{Ll})(\P{Ll}\p{Ll})",
                "$1 $2"
            ),
            @"(\p{Ll})(\P{Ll})",
            "$1 $2"
        );
    }

    private static bool IsTransformRequired(string propertyName, DisplayMetadata modelMetadata, IReadOnlyList<object> propertyAttributes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetadata.SimpleDisplayProperty))
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Where I saw that code, they enabled it in their Startup.cs class like this:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new HumaniserMetadataProvider());
    });
```

However, when I tried this myself with a Razor Page the label was not transformed in any way - it remained as 'EmailFromAddress'. Why would this not have worked? I also tried converting the Razor Page to an MVC controller but that didn't make a difference neither.

Here's a snippet from my view, which specified a model of 'SystemSettings':

```
<form method="post">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmailFromAddress)
    <div class="row m-t-md">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The EditorFor renders this string template:

```
@model string <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="m-b-none"></label>
    <span asp-description-for="@Model" class="help-block m-b-none small m-t-none"></span>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
        <vc:text-box></vc:text-box>
        <partial name="_ValidationIcon" />
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="validation-message"></span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of this line in the HumanizerMetadataProvider:

```
if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any())
            return false;
```

My model has a [Display] attribute in which I am specifying a Description like this:

```
[Display(Description = "Emails sent from system will be sent from this address.")]
public string EmailFromAddress { get; set; }
```

To get around this issue, I check if the value of the Display attribute's 'Name' property is null or empty. If it is, then I permit the transform. I modified the code in the HumanizerMetadataProvider like this:

```
if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any())
{
    var displayName = modelMetadata.DisplayName?.Invoke();
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName);
}
```