# How to implement custom metadata provider in .NET Core, for different display/edit formats based on datatype

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a custom model metadata provider class in .NET Core inheriting from `DefaultModelMetadataProvider`. The purpose is to have different date formats in display vs. edit, based on the datatype.

Here is a class that worked previously, ported to .NET Core:

```
public class ASLMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType,
        string propertyName)
    {
        ModelMetadata modelMetadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        // doing this here because DisplayFormatAttribute does not allow different formats for Display vs. Edit
        if (modelMetadata.DataTypeName == "Date")
        {
            modelMetadata.DisplayFormatString = DataFormatString.DateDisplay;
            modelMetadata.EditFormatString = DataFormatString.DateEdit;
        }

        return modelMetadata;
    }
}
```

I believe inheriting from `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` should work. I've changed the `ASLMetadataProvider` class above to inherit from `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` and implement 2 empty constructors, calling their base.

```
public ASLMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider) : base(detailsProvider)
{}

public ASLMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider, IOptions<MvcOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(detailsProvider, optionsAccessor)
{}
```

and tried overriding a couple methods such as:

```
public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForType(Type modelType))
{..}
```

I am unsure if this approach will work, which method to override and how to get the `modelMetaData` to check the datatype for before it's updated/returned, similar to `CreateMetadata` above

I've also updated program.cs with this line (and can see my methods above being called)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IModelMetadataProvider, ASLMetadataProvider>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chen's answer worked, with just a tweak!

In IsTransformRequired, I had to remove the DisplayAttribute check.
And for efficiency I replaced it with checking modelMetadata.DataTypeName exists

//if (propertyAttributes.OfType().Any())
//    return false;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetadata.DataTypeName))
return false;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably something like this:

```
public class ASLMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        var propertyAttributes = context.Attributes;
        var modelMetadata = context.DisplayMetadata;
        var propertyName = context.Key.Name;

        if (IsTransformRequired(propertyName, modelMetadata, propertyAttributes))
        {
            if (modelMetadata.DataTypeName == "Date")
            {
                modelMetadata.DisplayFormatString = "xxxxx";
                modelMetadata.EditFormatString = "xxxxx";
            }
                
        }
    }

    private static bool IsTransformRequired(string propertyName, DisplayMetadata modelMetadata, IReadOnlyList<object> propertyAttributes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetadata.SimpleDisplayProperty))
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(m => m.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new ASLMetadataProvider()));
```

The answer is referenced from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027881/humanizermetadataprovider-implementation-not-working-for-razor-page-model).